Issue trying to calculate with javascript
I have an issue trying to calculate the "new" price from dropbox selection. Here is my current codebase:
var orderTotal     = document.getElementById('order_amount_total');
var orderBasePrice = orderTotal.value;
var additionalIps  = document.getElementById('input_vps_ips');
var additionalCap  = document.getElementById('input_vps_cap');
var additionalDisk = document.getElementById('input_vps_disk');
var pricePerIP     = 25;

additionalIps.onchange = function(e) {
  var   totalIPPrice  = pricePerIP * e.target.value - 25;
  const newTotalPrice = parseFloat(orderTotal.value) + parseFloat(totalIPPrice);
  console.log(newTotalPrice);
  orderTotal.innerHTML = newTotalPrice.toString();
}

When I do
console.log(newTotalPrice);
the output in the console shows as NaN, while doing
console.log(totalIPPrice );
actually shows the new price that needs to be added to orderTotal.value, however it doesn't seem to let me add those two together.
The element order_amount_total is an span which contains a double.
I know float and double is alike, so I use parseFloat(), I'm not sure if there is a double parse and also not sure if that has anything to do with the issue.
Any clues on this?

<span> elements do not have a "value" property.

Log all the values involved, including orderTotal.value. Don't assume that any of them are what you think they are.

please show minimal HTML we only know that order_amount_total is a <select> ?,  but what about  input_vps_ips and other ? are they all <span> elements, or are they <input type="number"> ?  is there a <form> around, ... ?

Your orderTotal.value needs to be orderTotal.innerText, since a span does not have a value property.
var orderTotal     = document.getElementById('order_amount_total');
var orderBasePrice = orderTotal.value;
var additionalIps  = document.getElementById('input_vps_ips');
var additionalCap  = document.getElementById('input_vps_cap');
var additionalDisk = document.getElementById('input_vps_disk');
var pricePerIP     = 25;

additionalIps.onchange = function(e) {
  var   totalIPPrice  = pricePerIP * e.target.value - 25;
  const newTotalPrice = parseFloat(orderTotal.innerText) + parseFloat(totalIPPrice);
  console.log(newTotalPrice);
  orderTotal.innerHTML = newTotalPrice.toString();
}

